# Angular 12 - Check if its logged on startup - initializer working wrong

Tags: angular, typescript, graphql, jwt

I want to ask what could be wrong in my initializer, i test the refresh token and is going well (test when is executed with the startRefreshTokenTimer). The initializer is executing and sending the Bearer token in the header, the query refreshToken is tested and working (return a valid response). Meanwhile when used in the initializer responde like the header is not sended or is not valid the token, or idk. Maybe the token is loaded after the query is send but in the header i see the token.

AppModule

```
  providers: [
    { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: appInitializer, multi: true, deps: [AccountService] },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: JwtInterceptor, multi: true },
```

AccountService

```
export class AccountService {
  private tokenSubject: BehaviorSubject<String>;
  public token: Observable<String>;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private http: HttpClient,
    private apollo: Apollo,
    private localstorageService: LocalstorageService
  ) {
    this.tokenSubject = new BehaviorSubject<String>(
      JSON.parse(this.localstorageService.getToken()!)
    );
    this.token = this.tokenSubject.asObservable();

  }
   
  public get tokenValue(): String {
    return this.tokenSubject.value;
  }

  refreshToken() {
    return this.apollo
      .mutate({
        mutation: refreshToken,
      })
      .pipe(
        map((data: any) => {
          if (data.data.refreshToken.status) {
            this.tokenSubject.next(data.data.refreshToken.token);
            this.localstorageService.setToken(data.data.refreshToken.token);
            this.startRefreshTokenTimer();
            return data.data.refreshToken;
          }
          return null;
        })
      );
  }
```

Initializer

```
 export function appInitializer(accountService: AccountService) {
  if (accountService.tokenValue) {
    return () => new Promise(resolve => {
      // attempt to refresh token on app start up to auto authenticate
      accountService.refreshToken()
        .subscribe()
        .add(resolve);
    });
  } else {
    return () => new Promise((resolve) => resolve(true));
  };
 }
```

localstorageService

```
setToken(token: String) {
    localStorage.setItem('systemart', this.encryptData(JSON.stringify(token))!);
  }
  getToken() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('systemart')) {
      return this.decryptData(localStorage.getItem('systemart'));
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
  removeToken() {
    localStorage.removeItem('systemart');
  }
```

interceptor

```
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private accountService: AccountService) { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // add auth header with jwt if account is logged in and request is to the api url
    const token = this.accountService.tokenValue;
    const isApiUrl = request.url.startsWith(environment.apiUrl);

    if (token && isApiUrl) {
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
      });
    }
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was when reading localStorage. I read like JSON and have "" so the bearer token read wrong. Tks.